# Need to translating below simple query in tableau through calculated field

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I have below simple query in impala, and I can easily put this in data source to create my required chart, But I want this to be done in tableau, because of some other reasons.

I know tableau and calculated fields etc.. , but right now my mind is stuck and don't have any idea how to cope with this.

```
select cat_count,count(my_dim) from

(

select my_dim,

case when count(*) = 1 then 'A 1'
 when count(*) = 2 then 'B 2'

 when count(*) = 3 then 'C 3'

 when count(*) between 4 and 8 then 'D 4-8'

 when count(*) between 9 and 20000 then 'D >=9'end cat_count

 from my_table group by my_dim
```

) a

```
group by cat_count
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to create fixed bins, then count the numbers within those bins. Check this post about [creating fixed bins and counting the members in Tableau](https://tarsolutions.co.uk/blog/create-fixed-bins-from-a-measure-in-tableau/).